# UITabbar background image IPhone 6 issue

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, iphone-6

I'm developing Tab bar Application and found strange issue on iPhone 6
[image]

Notice that image is not wide enough for full screen but repeated.
I have set image through both storyboard and programmatically
I have also have 2x and 3x images placed in Images.xcassets

[image]

Comment: ever find an answer?

Comment: yes , not an answer but hack, let me post it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For any one who comes here later, here is what i do**

After Some tries i've used a hack as follow

- Do not used images from assets instead place them as files (we do before assets)
- Check if we have iPhone 6 and user @3x image, (i was not sure why it was not picked by assets but it do in this manner)

Following is code

```
#define isIPhone6 [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height > 568 ? YES : NO

UITabBar *tabBar = tabBarController.tabBar;
UIImage* tabBarBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_bar1.png"];
if (isIPhone6) {
    tabBarBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_bar2@3x.png"];
}
[tabBar setBackgroundImage:tabBarBackground];
```